# How to specify markers in YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a `YAML` file that is going to be parsed by two different machines, so I want to specify some sort of markers in the file to indicate which machine has the right to read a specific block. 
As an example I want the block 1 to be parsed by machine 1 and block 2 to be parsed by machine2:

```
 # BLOCK 1 - Machine 1
 -
  :id: 1234
  :worker: Foo1
  :opts:
    :ftpaccount: user1
    :limit: 10

# BLOCK 2 - Machine 2
 -
  :id: 5678
  :worker: Foo2
  :opts:
    :ftpaccount: user2
    :limit: 10
```

How can I achieve something like this? How you implement something similar to this? Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use a pre-processing block wrapped around `YAML.parse_stream`, but I guess my question is if you're taking the trouble to annotate the file, why not just provide different files to the two machines?

Comment: You should not put that in a single file. Have them in two different files, and let different machines read different files.

Comment: I have two copies of this file on both machines, this is actually a very long file, and I don't want to update this always in two places. and creating different files will lead me into issues.

Answer (score 3):

Treat the blocks as hash entries with the key being the hostname:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = <<EOT
host1:
  # BLOCK 1 - Machine 1
  -
    :id: 1234
    :worker: Foo1
    :opts:
      :ftpaccount: user1
      :limit: 10

host2:
  # BLOCK 2 - Machine 2
  -
    :id: 5678
    :worker: Foo2
    :opts:
      :ftpaccount: user2
      :limit: 10

EOT

config = YAML.load(yaml)
# => {"host1"=>
#      [{:id=>1234,
#        :worker=>"Foo1",
#        :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user1", :limit=>10}}],
#     "host2"=>
#      [{:id=>5678,
#        :worker=>"Foo2",
#        :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user2", :limit=>10}}]}
```

At this point you can grab the chunk you need:

```
config['host1']
# => [{:id=>1234, :worker=>"Foo1", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user1", :limit=>10}}]

config['host2']
# => [{:id=>5678, :worker=>"Foo2", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user2", :limit=>10}}]
```

You don't even have to hard-code the hostname; You can ask the machine what its name is:

```
`hostname`.chomp # => "MyHost"
```

Actually, I'd change the YAML a little, so it's a hash of hashes. As is, your YAML returns a hash of arrays of hashes, which, because of the array, makes it more awkward to use:

```
host1:
  # BLOCK 1 - Machine 1
  :id: 1234
  :worker: Foo1
  :opts:
    :ftpaccount: user1
    :limit: 10

host2:
  # BLOCK 2 - Machine 2
  :id: 5678
  :worker: Foo2
  :opts:
    :ftpaccount: user2
    :limit: 10
```

Results in:

```
config = YAML.load(yaml)
# => {"host1"=>
#      {:id=>1234, :worker=>"Foo1", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user1", :limit=>10}},
#     "host2"=>
#      {:id=>5678, :worker=>"Foo2", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user2", :limit=>10}}}

config['host1']
# => {:id=>1234, :worker=>"Foo1", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user1", :limit=>10}}

config['host2']
# => {:id=>5678, :worker=>"Foo2", :opts=>{:ftpaccount=>"user2", :limit=>10}}
```

Finally, if your YAML file is complex, or long, or has repeated sections, seriously consider writing code that emits that file for you. Ruby makes it really easy to generate the YAML in a very smart way that automatically uses aliases. For instance:

```
require 'yaml'

SOME_COMMON_DATA = {
  'shared_db_dsn' => 'mysql://user:password@host/db'
}

HOST1 = 'foo.com'
HOST1_DATA = {
  HOST1 => {
    'id' => 1234,
    'worker' => 'Foo1',
    'opts' => {
      'ftpaccount' => 'user1',
      'limit' => 10
    },
    'dsn' => SOME_COMMON_DATA
  }
}

HOST2 = 'bar.com'
HOST2_DATA = {
  HOST2 => {
    'id' => 5678,
    'worker' => 'Foo2',
    'opts' => {
      'ftpaccount' => 'user2',
      'limit' => 10
    },
    'dsn' => SOME_COMMON_DATA
  }
}

data = {
  HOST1 => HOST1_DATA,
  HOST2 => HOST2_DATA,
}

puts data.to_yaml
# >> ---
# >> foo.com:
# >>   foo.com:
# >>     id: 1234
# >>     worker: Foo1
# >>     opts:
# >>       ftpaccount: user1
# >>       limit: 10
# >>     dsn: &1
# >>       shared_db_dsn: mysql://user:password@host/db
# >> bar.com:
# >>   bar.com:
# >>     id: 5678
# >>     worker: Foo2
# >>     opts:
# >>       ftpaccount: user2
# >>       limit: 10
# >>     dsn: *1
```

Notice how YAML converted "`dsn`" into an alias and referenced it in the second host's definition using an anchor. This can add up to serious space savings, depending on how you define your variables and build the data structure. See "[Aliases and Anchors](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#aliases_and_anchors)" for more information.

Also, I'd highly recommend avoiding the use of symbols for your hash keys. By doing so your YAML can be easily loaded by other languages, not just Ruby. At that point, your YAML becomes even more useful when building big systems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but the `config['host1']` only returns the first block of host1, so this will not work if we have multiple blocks of `host1`.

Comment: Then you embed them in the 'host1' hash. We use this technique for some complex YAML being used by multiple apps that need to have access to common, and unique/special, data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple state machine that assembles a string based on the most recent matching comment in the yaml file. The YAML string is then loaded into the parser. If your files are really large, you could easily modify this to use `Tempfile` or some other IO class.

```
require 'yaml'

class YAMLSplitter
  attr_reader :flag, :mode, :raw
  def initialize(flag)
    @flag = flag
    @mode = :match
    @raw = ""
  end

  def parse(file)
    File.read(file).each_line do |line|
      process_line(line)
    end

    YAML.load(raw)
  end

  private

    def process_line(line)
      set_match_status(line)
      write_line(line) if match?
    end

    def set_match_status(line)
      if line.start_with?("#")
        if line.match(flag)
          match!
        else
          nomatch!
        end
      end
    end

    def write_line(line)
      puts "WRITE_LINE #{mode.inspect} #{line.inspect}"
      raw << line
    end

    def match?
      mode == :match
    end

    def match!
      @mode = :match
    end

    def nomatch!
      @mode = :nomatch
    end

end
```

YAML:

```
---
# machine 1
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
# machine 2
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9
- 10
- 11
# machine 1
- 12
```

Execution:

```
splitter = YAMLSplitter.new('machine 1')
yaml = splitter.parse('test.yml')
```